# Vue Router Redirect to Login page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to test my Vue.js app authentication.

Assume, a user log in and to go to his profile the link would look like this.
https://website.com/profile/1

He can get to his page but what if he is a hacker and if he tried to type

https://website.com/profile/2

which will go to the profile of another person.

How can I redirect this hacker to the login page if he tried to go to a URL that does not belong to his profile?

Right now, I can stop him from viewing another people profile but still, he is still in the profile link even if he typed

https://website.com/profile/2

What I am trying to accomplish is that if users type a link that does not belong to his or her but which is valuable to other people it will redirect to the login page.

I am not storing User Data on the client side.

Comment: Have you looked into [beforeEnter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) function in your router?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to assume that the user is able to manipulate the webpage in any way and access all data stored on the client side. So you should not be storing sensitive data on the client that you do not want the user to access. (You may not be doing this, but I thought I should point it out.)

I assume you have a Profile component. You can use [Vue Router navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to authorize the transition and abort or redirect it if it is disallowed.

If the user is logged in then you are probably storing information about the logged in user on the client. You can use this to check if the profile page being visited belongs to the logged in user.

In your Profile component:

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  if (!loggedInUser) {
    // User not logged in
    next('/')
  } else if (loggedInUser.id !== to.params.userId) {
    // User is accessing profile page of another user, redirect
    // to their profile page instead
    next({ params: { userId: loggedInUser.id } })
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

This is just an example of what you can do, I can't give a specific answer without knowing exactly how your app works.

Comment: Can I use beforeEach instead of beforeRouteEnter? Are they different?

Comment: Sure, just check the docs. `beforeEach` is a global guard that is defined directly on the router instance instead of within the Profile component, so you'll have to do extra checks to confirm that the `/profile` route was matched.

Comment: Hi, can I get to.params.userId if I used beforeEach as a global guard? I can get the loggedInUser but I need to get the to.params.userId to compare?

Comment: Yes, all the navigation guards work basically the same. How is your route configured? Is your param named `userId`?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I called it is id but I think it is the same as you called userId. And it worked for me.

Comment: I think this is just an extra question but do you know how to custom the id so that people cannot see it or like turn it into something else? I am not sure what is the best practise for this.

Comment: Why does it matter if the user ID is visible in the URL? If you don’t want to be a part of the URL then you have to store the user ID locally within the app somewhere (eg global variable).

Comment: I just wonder if there is a way to be more secure but maybe this is secure enough. I just wonder maybe hackers can take advantage of the user ID. I do not know how smart they are so I just wonder. But for now, my app authentication seems secure enough.

Comment: If you're concerned about security, that needs to be done 100% server-side first and foremost.